# PHP MySQL Chinese UTF-8 Issue

Tags: php, mysql, encoding, utf-8, cjk

I have a MySQL table & fields that are all set to UTF-8. The thing is, a previous PHP script, which was in charge of the database writing, was using some other encoding, not sure whether it is in the script itself, the MySQL connection or somewhere else. The result is that although the table & fields are set to UTF-8, we see the wrong chars instead of Chinese.
It looks like that:

[image]

Now, the previous scripts (which were in charge of the writing and corrupted the data) can read it well for some reason, but my new script which all encoded in UTF-8, shows chars like ½©. How can that be fixed?

Comment: Hm, have you tried to read data and check it using [mb_detect_encoding](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-detect-encoding.php) function? Give it a try, maybe you can find out what is original encoding.

Comment: hmm yup played with it a bit, but i think its solved now, just added mysql query with `SET NAMES latin1` and it looks ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the sound of it, you have a utf8 column but you are writing to it and reading from it using a latin1 connection, so what is actually being stored in the table is mis-encoded. Your problem is that when you read from the table using a utf8 connection, you see the data that's actually stored there, which is why it looks wrong. You can fix the mis-encoded data in the table by converting to latin1, then back to utf8 via the binary character set (three steps in total).

Answer (score 0):

The original database was in a Chinese encoding – GB-18030 or similar, **not** Latin-1 – and the bytes that make up these characters, when displayed in UTF-8, show up as a bunch of Latin diacritics. Read each string as GB-18030, convert it to UTF-8, and save.